# WPF User Control XAML Commands

Tags: wpf, user-controls, binding, command

I've got a 3.5 WPF User Control with two buttons and I'd like to be able to bind commands to these buttons via the User Control's xaml.

```
x:Usercontrol x:Name:fou Button1Command="{Binding  StuffCommandHandler}" Button2Command="{Binding  Stuff2CommandHandler}"
```

Problem is the above bindings are not working.
How can I bind commands to the User control's buttons, two of them, via xaml?

I've got this in the UserControl's code behind and I bind Button1CommandHandler to Button1.Command

```
   private ICommand _button1Command;
   public ICommand Button1CommandHandler
    {
        get { return _button1Command; }
        set { _button1Command = value; }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make `Button1CommandHandler` into a dependency property:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonCommandProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ButtonCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(TwoButtons), new PropertyMetadata(default(ICommand)));

public ICommand ButtonCommand
{
    get { return (ICommand)GetValue(ButtonCommandProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ButtonCommandProperty, value); }
}
```

and then bind your button's `Command` to it. If you create the button from code, you can bind it like this:

```
button.SetBinding(Button.CommandProperty, new Binding("ButtonCommand") { Source = this });
```

Comment: working better, Button1.Command = ButtonCommand but ButtonCommand is null when control is created which is understandable. However, the Buttoncommand set isn't being fired when then xaml binding happens, so StuffCommandHandler is never fired when hte button is clicked. What am I missing?

Comment: I put a break point of the ButtonCommand set and it never fires

Comment: Button1 is being created dynamically via code, How do you bind a command via code (C#)?

Comment: @mike, see edited answer. If you just assign the `ButtonCommand` property to your button's `Command` when it's not yet initialized, you just assign `null` to it, it doesn't somehow automagically know where did that `null` come from. You have to use binding.